# ¿Cómo obtengo la cantidad dígitos, letras (mayúsculas y minúsculas) y caracteres de un input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Intento crear una validación para el campo de contraseña y quiero que exija:

- 2 mayúsculas,
- 2 minúsculas,
- 2 dígitos y
- 2 caracteres;

para cada uno de ellos que genere una puntuación, es decir, si ingresa 1 mayúscula generara 1 punto, si escribe 2 pues 2 puntos (pero hasta allí por cada tipo), y así para las demás. En total todas deben de generar 8 puntos, cuando obtenga 8 puntos aceptar la contraseña.

Lo que llevo hasta ahorita (pero solo me genera 6pts):

```
var score = 0;

if (value === '') {
  return {
    valid: true,
    score: null
  };
}

if (value.search(/[0-9]/) == 1) {
  score = score+1;
}else if (value.search(/[0-9]/) > 1) {
  score = score+2;
}

if (value.search(/[a-z]/) == 1) {
  score = score+1;
}else if (value.search(/[a-z]/) > 1) {
  score = score+2;
}

if (value.search(/[A-Z]/) == 1) {
  score = score+1;
}else if (value.search(/[A-Z]/) > 1) {
  score = score+2;
}

if (value.search(/[!#$%&^~*_-]/) == 1) {
  score = score+1;
}else if (value.search(/[!#$%&^~*_-]/) > 1) {
  score = score+2;
}

if(score < 8){
  return {
    valid: false,
    score: score,
  };
}else{
  return {
    valid: true,
    score: score
  };
}
```

En ese código:

- `value`: valor del input
- `score`: donde se acumula la puntuación

Comment: El código compartido parece JavaScript puro sin jQuery

Comment: ¿Qué significa "2 caracteres"? O sea, ¿qué estaría incluido dentro de esos 2 caracteres que se exigen?... Y por otro lado, ¿Qué sentido tiene obtener puntajes, si al fin y al cabo sólo te interesa 2 de cada uno de los tipos exigidos?

Comment: Yo lo busque y encontré como jQuery, como chequear la cantidad de caracteres que hay en una cadena y conseguí eso. A partir de ahí saque las demás. @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @Mariano 2 caracteres = 2 letras. Que debajo del input de la contraseña tengo una barra de progreso y se ira cargando a partir de la puntuación que lleve la contraseña que esta indicando el usuario, cuando llegue a 100% es porque cumplio todos los requerimientos. 2 = 25%, 4 = 50%, 6 = 75% y 8 = 100%.

Comment: Corrijo el comentario anterior: 2 caracteres = 2 caracteres especiales. Ej: !#$%&^~*_-

Comment: Me equivoque en lo que escribi, disculpa @Mariano

Comment: El problema que te estás encontrando es que `search` no hace lo que crees que hace

Comment: Eso llegue a pensar :/ , ¿con que método puedo obtener la cantidad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema que te estás encontrando es que [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/search) no hace lo que crees que hace. **`search` devuelve la posición (índice) de la primera subcadena que cumpla con la expresión regular**, pero lo estás utilizando como si devolviese el número de veces que se encontró la subcadena.

Entonces el código que tienes no te va a valer, en particular porque siempre que se encuentre uno de los caracteres válidos en la primera posición de la cadena (índice 0), `search` devolverá ese 0, no se entrará en el `if` y el valor añadido será 0. Por lo tanto lo máximo que vas a obtener como valor siempre será 6.

Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer para cada expresión regular es lo siguiente:

1. Si el resultado del `search` es -1: no se ha encontrado una subcadena que cumpla el patrón

   - `score` se quedará igual.
2. Si el valor del `search` es mayor o igual a 0: se encontró el patrón,

   1. `score` se incrementará en 1
   2. Se creará una nueva cadena que contendrá el valor de la cadena desde la posición en la que se encontró el patrón hasta el final.
   3. Volver a hacer el `search`

      - Si el resultado es -1: no se encontró una segunda subcadena que cumpla el patrón
      - Si el resultado es mayor o igual que 0: se encontró otra subcadena que cumpla el patrón; `score` se incrementará en 1.

---

Y una implementación de un algoritmo que haga algo como eso:

```js
function chequear() {
  var value = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var score = 0;

  if (value === '') {
    return {
      valid: false,
      score: null
    };
  }

  var exps = [ /[0-9]/, /[a-z]/, /[A-Z]/, /[!#$%&^~*_-]/ ];

  for (var x = 0; x < exps.length; x++) {
    var pos1 = value.search(exps[x]);
    if (pos1 > -1) {
      score++;
      var subcadena = value.substring(pos1+1);
      if (subcadena.search(exps[x]) > -1) {
        score++;
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    valid: score == (exps.length *2),
    score: score
  };

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password" />
<input type="button" value="Chequear" onclick="console.log(chequear())" />
```

Comment: ¿value o score? me refiero al valor que se incrementa

Comment: @PabloContreras es `score`. Gracias por comentarlo. Te he puesto un ejemplo de cómo sería el código

Comment: +1 ... Siguiendo esta lógica, quizás te sea más sencillo usar https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match con el modificador `/g` ... así se evitaría tener que obtener una subcadena

Comment: He cambiado el código para que no se repita lo mismo 4 veces (al principio lo tenía más parecido al código original de OP). La idea es que pongo los patrones en un array y hago un bucle simple, así no hay que repetir lo mismo una y otra vez

Comment: @Mariano ¿usando `match` en lugar de `search`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro exacto... Devuelve un array con las coincidencias, de esa forma se puede usar `match.length`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¿a quien le doy la puntuación? las respuestas de ambos están buenas y funcionan, ambos se dedicaron, me colocan en una mala posición xD

Comment: @MarcosGallardo totalmente correcto. He corregido el código para que no tenga magic number y sea más genérica. Gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 3):

#### Código

El objetivo que estás buscando se puede realizar con una única expresión regular, evitando compilar y ejecutar 4 expresiones.

```js
function puntajeDeClave(value) {
    var score = null,
           re = /^(?=([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-]([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-])?)?)(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]([^A-Z]*[A-Z])?)?)(?=([^a-z]*[a-z]([^a-z]*[a-z])?)?)(\D*\d(\D*\d)?)?/,
            m;

    m = re.exec(value);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++)   // contar cuántas capturas hay
        if (m[i] != null)
            score++;

    return {
      valid: (score == 8), 
      score: score
    };
}


//Codigo para probarlo
document.getElementById('clave')
.addEventListener('input', function(evt){
    var   clave = evt.target.value,
        puntaje = puntajeDeClave(clave);
  
    document.getElementById('resultado')
            .innerText = JSON.stringify(puntaje);
});
```

```html
<input type = "text"
       id   = "clave">
<pre   id   = "resultado"></pre>
```

#### Descripción:

La expresión regular es bastante larga, pero ahora la analizaremos y veremos que son simplemente pocas estructuras repetidas. (Nota: es un mito que una expresión regular más larga es menos eficiente, en este caso obtiene un mejor resultado).

Dividiendo en partes:

```
#Coincide sólo a partir del inicio del texto
/^

#1. coincide con 0, 1 o 2 caracteres especiales (no consume posiciones)
(?=([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-]([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-])?)?)

#2. coincide con 0, 1 o 2 mayúsculas (no consume posiciones)
(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]([^A-Z]*[A-Z])?)?)

#3. coincide con 0, 1 o 2 minúsculas (no consume posiciones)
(?=([^a-z]*[a-z]([^a-z]*[a-z])?)?)

#4. coincide con 0, 1 o 2 dígitos
(\D*\d(\D*\d)?)?
/
```

**Inspección hacia adelante**

Lo primero a explicar es la estructura `(?=` `subpatrón` `)` que engloba a las 3 primeras partes.
Esta es una [inspección hacia adelante](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) (o *[lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*). Esta construcción hace que se deba coincidir con el `subpatrón`, pero luego de que coincida, el resto de la expresión regular se sigue intentando desde la posición en la que estaba antes de intentar esta *inspección hacia adelante*. Es decir, para el regex de esta respuesta, luego de intentar una parte, la siguiente se intentará de nuevo desde el principio del texto. Por eso ***no consume caracteres***.

Por supuesto, como la 4ta parte es la última, no es necesario usar una inspección, porque no es necesario volver al inicio del texto.

**0, 1 o 2 caracteres**

Luego, todas las partes tienen la misma estructura, y sólo se diferencian en los caracteres.
Si los caracteres buscados fuesen `[x]`, la estructura es:

Grupo 1 (opcional):

```
([^x]*[x]([^x]*[x])?)?
```

- `[^x]*[x]` - coincide con cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no son `x`, seguidos de 1 caracter `x`, seguido de:
- Grupo 2 (opcional):

  ```
  ([^x]*[x])?
  ```

  - `[^x]*[x]` - igual al anterior, cualquier cantidad de no `x` y 1 `x`.

Como cada parte es opcional, puede no coincidir con ningún caracter `x`.
Si hay 1 `x` en el texto, el grupo 1 coincide, y el 2 no: `([^x]*[x]`<s>`([^x]*[x])?`</s>`)?`.
Si hay 2 `x` en el texto, ambos grupos coinciden: `([^x]*[x]([^x]*[x])?)?`.

Repetido para los 4 tipos de caracteres buscados:

1. `([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-]([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-])?)?`
2. `([^A-Z]*[A-Z]([^A-Z]*[A-Z])?)?`
3. `([^a-z]*[a-z]([^a-z]*[a-z])?)?`
4. `(\D*\d(\D*\d)?)?`

**Grupos y capturas**

Como vimos recién, usamos 2 grupos opcionales por cada tipo de caracter. Pero usar grupos tiene un beneficio importante extra: el texto que coincide con un grupo es ***capturado***.

[RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), devuelve un array con la coincidencia global en el primer índice, y cada uno de los textos capturados en los siguientes índices del array. Y aquí está el punto principal de la solución utilizada: sólo tenemos que contar cuántos grupos capturaron texto, por eso el loop incrementando el puntaje por cada captura que no es `null`.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    if (m[i] != null)
        score++;
```

Comment: Mola. Debería esperar a ver cómo funciona para el +1, pero sé que funcionará bien :P

Comment: @Mariano ¿a quien le doy la puntuación? las respuestas de ambos están buenas y funcionan, ambos se dedicaron, me colocan en una mala posición xD

Comment: @Mariano tranquilo, disculpa lo que opine. Gracias por la dedicación al responder.

Comment: okok Gracias :D

Comment: Es muy difícil leer y entender una expresión regular tan larga como ésta (aunque sea eficaz). Yo pondría cada parte en una variable, algo así: `var especiales = '(?=([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-]([^!#$%&^~*_-]*[!#$%&^~*_-])?)?)', mayusculas = '(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]([^A-Z]*[A-Z])?)?)'` etc., y luego `var re = '/^' + especiales + mayusculas + minusculas + digitos + '/'`. De esta manera es más fácil ver cómo se construye esta expresión, y por tanto más fácil leerla (y cambiarla cuando sea necesario).

Answer (score 2):

**Una solución sin expresiones regulares**

```js
function calcularPuntaje(clave) {
    var especiales = '!#$%&^~*_-',
        mayusculas = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        minusculas = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        digitos = '0123456789';
        
     var puntosEspeciales = 0,
         puntosMayusculas = 0,
         puntosMinusculas = 0,
         puntosDigitos = 0,
         puntosTotal = 0;
         
     for (var i = 0; i < clave.length; i++) {
         if (especiales.includes(clave[i]))
             puntosEspeciales = Math.min(puntosEspeciales + 1, 2);
         if (mayusculas.includes(clave[i]))
             puntosMayusculas = Math.min(puntosMayusculas + 1, 2);
         if (minusculas.includes(clave[i]))
             puntosMinusculas = Math.min(puntosMinusculas + 1, 2);
         if (digitos.includes(clave[i]))
             puntosDigitos = Math.min(puntosDigitos + 1, 2);
     }
     
     puntosTotal = puntosEspeciales + puntosMayusculas + puntosMinusculas + puntosDigitos;
     
     return {
         valid: (puntosTotal >= 8),
         score: puntosTotal
     }
}

//Codigo para probarlo -- igual en la respuesta de @Mariano
document.getElementById('clave')
.addEventListener('input', function(evt){
    var   clave = evt.target.value,
        puntaje = calcularPuntaje(clave);
  
    document.getElementById('resultado')
            .innerText = JSON.stringify(puntaje);
});
```

```html
<input type = "text"
       id   = "clave">
<pre   id   = "resultado"></pre>
```